# CKEditor editable content in IFrame

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to run ckeditor on an IFrame so that can encapsulate a full html page?  I have tried various methods but nothing seems to work.

What I am looking for is to have a ckeditor wrapper page say Editor.htm which contains an editable IFrame linked to my real html page say test.htm.  Something line:

Editor.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe contenteditable="true" src="test.htm" id="editor1" name="editor1"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set ckeditor to use "fullPage" mode, allowing you to edit everything from the opening  tag to the closing  tag. See the official sample [here](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fullpage.html).

You will still need to get the content into the editor (e.g. the html page you want to edit) and save the result on the server, but this is something specific to your site, language, platform etc.